# Firefox/Opera password manager

Tags: password, opera

On Windows machines, Firefox and Opera both will fill in and save passwords in the password manager.  Why does it not function the same way in Ubuntu?

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by Password Manager?

Answer (score 0):

Also in Ubuntu, Firefox will auto-complete usernames and passwords, unless you except a specific web page. Opera does not do so, but it has a **key**-shaped button beside the web badge (or a shortcut-key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) to login automatically.

[image: Opera Log-in Button]

Opera, unlike Firefox or Chrome, won't show saved passwords in Password Manager – I like this security guard.